# If statement is not working in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

Iam trying to create a simple if statement in Excel with VBA.

I'm creating a new checkbox

Adds the following code to the box.

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
   HideRows "2:5"
End Sub

Sub HideRows(rowRange)
If CheckBox1 = False Then
   Rows(rowRange).EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Else: Rows(rowRange).EntireRow.Hidden = False
   End If
End Sub
```

Result: The rows are hidden both if the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

(checkbox is checked)

All rows are visible

Uncheck the  checkbox

Result: All rows are hidden

(checkbox is unchecked)

All rows are visible

Uncheck the  checkbox

Result: All rows are hidden

Answer (score 4):

You want it in a Change Event.

You do not need the If Then.  `CheckBox1` rturns a TRUE/FALSE, just use that.

And the `EntireRow` is also not needed when refering to `Rows()`.  You are already refering to the whole row.

Also, it is good practice to always declare the parent to any Range Object, which `Rows()` is.  If the the code is in the Worksheet code then use `Me` as it will refer to itself.  If the code is in a module then use `ActiveSheet` or more preferably the specific sheet, `Worksheets("Sheet1")` :

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
    HideRows "2:5"
End Sub



Sub HideRows(rowRange)
   'if this code is not in the worksheet code then change `Me` to `ActiveSheet`
   Me.Rows(rowRange).Hidden = Not CheckBox1

End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoted for pointing out the redundancy of the `If...Then` block and Boolean assignments... I'd qualify `Rows` with `ActiveSheet` and explicitly refer to `CheckBox1.Value` though ;-)

Comment: What he said ^^^^

Comment: @Mat'sMug though, if this is on the sheet code is it really needed or would `Me` be better?

Comment: Ah, yes, absolutely - I keep assuming comboboxes are on userforms :)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I'm just glad I was able to get the +1 from you.  I've been trying to step up my vba answers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming its an ActiveX CheckBox, place this code in Sheet Module...

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1 = True Then
    Rows("2:5").Hidden = True
Else
    Rows("2:5").Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

Or just use this...

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Rows("2:5").Hidden = CheckBox1
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just `ActiveSheet.Rows("2:5").Hidden = CheckBox1.Value`?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes, that's true. But it was just to demonstrate how it would work rather than finding the shortest method to achieve the end result. What you suggested actually doesn't even require to qualify it with sheet reference as the code will be sitting in the sheet module itself. :)

Comment: That's correct (+1) - the applicable explicit qualifier would be `Me` if that code is in a worksheet's code-behind; arguably the active sheet would/should be *that sheet* though, but yeah `Me` is semantically more appropriate than `ActiveSheet`... and `Me` is always a redundant qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in one sub, assuming its an activeX checkbox

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1 = True Then
    [2:5].EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else: [2:5].EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```